# Undefined functions when using mobx store with class instance as property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, observable, mobx

I am using mobx and decimal.js.
This is my store:

```
import Decimal from "decimal.js";
import { makeObservable, observable, action } from "mobx";

class MyStore {
  public value: Decimal | null = null;

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      value: observable,

      setValue: action,
    });
  }

  public setValue() {
    this.value = new Decimal(100);
  }
}

export { MyStore };
```

This is my component:

```
import { useStoreValue } from "../../state/StoreContext";
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";

const MyPage = observer(() => {

  const value = useStoreValue((rootStore) => rootStore.myStore.value);

  return <span>{value.mul(5)}</span>;
});

export { MyPage };
```

As a result I get the following exception:

```
useObserver.ts:119 Uncaught TypeError: _value.mul is not a function
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Where do you call `setValue()?`

Comment: @IvanV. Somewhere in my app. The value I set is Decimal instance.